# How do I calculate xi^j in a matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to calculate a matrix from an array that is inputted.

I would like to be able to input

```
a = [0,1,2]
```

in python and would like to reshape it with Numpy such that the result is that the array is in the form of x_i^j at row i and column j,

so for example 
the input is:

```
    a = [0,1,2]
```

and the output should be

```
[[1,0,0],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,2,4]]
```

and I have used the following code

```
 xij = np.matrix([np.power(xi,j) for j in x for xi in x]).reshape(3,3)

[[ 1,  2,  3],
 [ 1,  4,  9],
 [ 1,  8, 27]]
```

I assume I'm using the wrong formula for Numpy,
please could you assist me in this to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your problem well, you example output should be `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 4, 16]]`, should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `range(len(a))` to get the exponents and the correct order of for loops

```
a = [0,1,2]

xij = np.matrix([np.power(xi,j) for xi in a for j in range(len(a))]).reshape(3,3)

# matrix([[1, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1],
#         [1, 2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

With array broadcasting:

```
In [823]: np.array([0,1,2])**np.arange(3)[:,None]                               
Out[823]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 4]])

In [825]: np.array([1,2,3])**np.arange(1,4)[:,None]                             
Out[825]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  4,  9],
       [ 1,  8, 27]])
```